# Regex: Removing unwanted characters from string incl. "()"

Tags: regex

I would very much appreciate help in this matter. I'm kind of new at Regex. In this specific issue, I'm working in Sharepoint 2013 with a regular expression.

I am given this string:

> CN=Søren Holten (dbo-sho),OU=Users,OU=KON,OU=Corporate Users,OU=DK (Denmark),DC=root,DC=local

I'd need to be returned only the chars in the first brackets. In this case the expected result would be:

> dbo-sho

Most data in the string are variables, so I can't used fixed numbers of chars etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
(?<=\()[^\(\)]+(?=\))
```

Don't use global modifier `g`. The above will work.

Comment: Thanks. But the output is wrong. I got "Søren Holten". Should have been "dbo-sho".